# How to set GRUB dual boot if ubuntu and BIOS can't detect my windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

My BIOS can see both discs with ubuntu and windows 10. It detects ubuntu, but sees disc with windows just as 256gb ssd.
If i choose first boot option 256gb ssd, it loads windows.
If i choose first option ubuntu it loads it.
I tried os-probe, it doesn't detect windows.
I tried suggested option in windows to turn off quickload, didn't help.
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

So i guess the main question is, how to make my windows bee seeable?

UPD:
When i first set up ubuntu, grub did see windows and everything worked fine untill i had to remove my 3rd hard drive that i used just as storage because it stopped working. After that i got error invalid efi filepath. Then i went to recovery in grub and used option to update grub. After that grub didn't show up anymore and when i push right shift, there is no windows option anymore.

One more solution i tried to edit /etc/grub.d/40_custom and then update grub, but got
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub' Sourcing file` /etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-43-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

lsblk -f -e 7
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda
├─sda1
│
├─sda2
│    vfat   FAT32       BA01-6CAB                             505,9M     1% /boot/efi
└─sda3
ext4   1.0         91e73974-1b3c-4814-bff2-61263d58a3b9   83,4G    23% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
/
sdb
├─sdb1
│    ntfs         Reserved by system
│                       B6EB95EF6DA8AF03
├─sdb2
│    ntfs               D55CCFCB589CBFFB
└─sdb3
ntfs               4BC8F7948C88857F
sdc
└─sdc1
ntfs         Warehouse
469861A098618EED

warehouse does not have any OS, just a storage.

[Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)
i used boot repair and got this, though don't know what that means.
LegacyWindows has been detected. Enable BIOS/CSM/Legacy compatibility mode in the computer's UEFI settings and use the program by booting from a Live CD (or Live USB).
[image]

Comment: You mention ensuring *fastboot* is off (*you call it quickload*), but some forms of encryption can also *hide* the appearance of windows too.  Unless you're happy to remove some forms of encryption (*if that's your issue*) you maybe out of luck, but you've provided no Ubuntu product & release details so we're somewhat needing to guess.  What Ubuntu system are you asking about?

Comment: This is a Q&A site and not a forum, please edit your question & add additional details, or clarifications there. Comments are only that (*comments*) and any *answers* will be to your question which still doesn't mention any Ubuntu product details (ie. no Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop etc).

Comment: If this problem arose when you removed a failed disk and you got EFI path errors then that sounds like you no longer have the EFI partition that grub originally used. If you add the output of `lsblk -f -e 7` to your question that might help clarify things

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: If your first boot option is a disk it usually means legacy boot, your second boot option is called ubuntu then it indicates EFI boot mode. Looks like you mixed up boot modes.

Comment: Was Windows originally on the HDD you removed? I think you lost a Windows EFI partition when that died. How old is your Windows installation. Unless it started as a Windows 7 it’s highly likely that you have lost the EFI partition that boots Windows. You can fix that by reinstalling Windows although there may be other solutions. If you do reinstall Windows temporarily disconnect the disk (sda) with Ubuntu on it while you reinstall. Afterwards grub should be able to find Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions. Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration. Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.


os-prober has been disabled, you have to edit `/etc/default/grub`
to add: `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` and run `sudo update-grub`

[related](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/warning-os-prober-will-not-be-executed-to-detect-other-bootable-partitions/57849/2)

Comment: We're not talking about Manjaro here, but Ubuntu.  Yes that change was *noticed* during the *alpha* stage (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2021-December/041769.html) and noticed in QA-testing (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1955109) and you'll note it was resolved well before Ubuntu 22.04 LTS was released (*even before it reached BETA too!*)

Comment: didn't do anything, result the same as above